# Why java monothread is capped at 25% on a dual core (i5)

Tags: java, cpu

Good morning,

first of all i do not have a quad core, but an i5 (dual core) on Windows7. When my java programm is launched (mono thread on Eclipse) and performing endless computations the "windows task performance panel" is never showing a cpu usage over 25-30%.

I would understand that on a quad core (a thread is running on a core), but here I would have expected 50%. In fact Windows is showing 4 cpu curves, so i suppose that a core is logically divided in 2, but at the end my computer have only two physical cores.

So why am i capped at 25 % ? (others threads running and not monitored, wrong information coming from the monitoring ...etc...options not activated in the Jvm)

Thank you for your help
regards
jcl

Comment: I am guessing the JVM asks for cpu time from the OS, the OS is not obliged to provide 100%.

Comment: each core has 2 threads.

Comment: this might help http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#perf%5Fscaling

Comment: Is Hyperthreading enabled on the cpu?  This will show up as four cpu's in Task Manager.

Answer (score 8):

Your processor uses [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), so the 2 physical cores become 4 logical cores.

Now as you've only got a single thread, that can only use one of those logical cores - i.e. 25% of your available logical cores, hence the capping. If you change your application to use multiple threads (assuming that's feasible in your particular task) then you'll see more cores being used.

You *may* find that you can turn off hyper-threading in your BIOS, at which point I'd expect Windows to report 2 cores instead of 4. You *may* then find that your application runs faster than it did before - but there'll be a lot of different factors in that calculation. (Modern processors are rather smart, and do all kinds of things automatically - such as turning off unused cores and boosting the clock speed of the still-used ones if they detect a small number of busy cores.)

Comment: Perhaps you would like to use the opportunity to describe the difference between a core and a thread (in this context)?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: Not sure. Currently 25 minutes away from giving a presentation, so don't want to get into anything which might require more replies later...